# post by input file and text in one form using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

im using ajax to post file and text in a form, When I use the file and the text input simultaneously, I get into trouble , this is my form:

```html
    <form action="insertbook.php" method="post" id="addBookForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table >
        <!-- 1- IMAGE -->
        <tr>
            <td>Image:</td>
            <td>
                <input accept="image/gif, image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg"
                    type="file" name="img_data" id="img_data">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <!-- 2- NAME-->
        <tr>
            <td>Book Name: </td>
            <td >
                <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- 3- CATEGORY -->
        <tr>
            <td>Book Cat: </td>
            <td>
                <select id="cat_dropdown" onchange="selectionCatchange()">
                        <?php for ($i=0; $i< sizeof($cats); $i++ ) { 
                        echo '<option  value="'.$cats[$i]['id'].'" >'. $cats[$i]['cat_name'] .'</option>';
                         } ?>
                </select>
                <?php echo 
                '<input  id="cat_id" name="cat_id" value="'. $cats[0]['id'] .'"  type="hidden">' ;
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr> 

        <!-- SUBMIT -->
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" >
                <input id="insertbook" type="submit" name="submit" >
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

In Javascript codes, We have:

```js
$("#addBookForm").submit(function(e) {
    /* Stop form from submitting normally */
    e.preventDefault();
    /* Get some values from elements on the page: */
    var title = document.getElementById('title').value;
    var img_data = $('#img_data').prop('files')[0];
    var cat_id = document.getElementById('cat_id').value;
    var submit = "submit";
    $.ajax({
        url: "insertbook.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {'title':title,
                 'img_data':img_data,
                'cat_id':cat_id,
                'submit':submit
                },
        dataType:'html',
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
        },
        error:function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    }); 
});
```

But in PHP Code, following this:

```
<?php 
     $conn = mysqli_connect(****);
     mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
    if( 
        isset($_POST['title']) && 
        isset($_POST['cat_id']) && 
        isset($_POST['submit']) 
        && 
        isset($_FILES['img_data'])
     ){

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $cat_id = $_POST['cat_id'];

    // THIS SECTION RELATE TO IMAGE UPLOAD
    $name_img = basename($_FILES['img_data']['name']);
    $type_img = strtolower($_FILES['img_data']['type']);
    $data_img = file_get_contents($_FILES['img_data']['tmp_name']);

    $uploadOk = 1;
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["img_data"]["size"] > 2097152) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large > 2 Mb!";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your image file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (mysqli_query( $conn,"INSERT INTO `books`( `title`, `img`, `cat_id`, `created_at`) VALUES ('$title','".addslashes($data_img)."', '$cat_id', NOW())" )) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    }}else{echo "Please set all information...!!! ";}
?>
```

But in the end I get the following error every time:

> **Notice**:  Undefined index: img_data in *****\insertbook.php***** on line **6**
>  
>   **Notice**:  Undefined index: img_data in **\insertbook.php** on line **22**
>   
>   **Notice**:  Undefined index: img_data in *****\insertbook.php**** on line **23**
>   
>   **Notice**:  Undefined index: img_data in *****insertbook.php** on line **24**
>   
>   **Warning**:  file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in ***\insertbook.php** on line **24**
>   
>   **Notice**:  Undefined index: img_data in *****\insertbook.php** on line **34**
> New record created successfully

But in the end there is no file stored in the database and only one empty record is created, hopefully you can help guide me through the problem.
Thanks

Comment: You can inspect the xhr in the browser console. The first issue is that while your form has `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, your `$.ajax` call doesn't set that header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should try this**

Remove `action` `method` and `enctype` attributes from `from` tag element.

Try with sending data using `new FormData()` in ajax.

```
$("#addBookForm").on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    formData.append('submit', 'submit');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'insertbook.php',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },          
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Some problem occurred, please try again.");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: when i  added `contentType: false, processData: false,`
and change  `data: {'title':title,
                 'img_data':img_data,
                'cat_id':cat_id,
                'submit':submit
                },` to  `var formData = new FormData(this);` then `data: formData,` my problem solved, Thank You<3 :)

Comment: @HajAli My Pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

To check a file input if it is set or not is this.

Change this art in your if condition

```
isset($_FILES['img_data'])
```

To this

```
isset($_FILES['img_data']['name'])
```